# Room's custom properties don't get updated | Photon PUN2 | Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have a system where a player can create a room and then other players can join that room. At any point the master client can change scenes for everyone in the room and they can start playing but other players can still join the room and will instantly get their scenes synced.
However I would like to show the players that are choosing a room to join whether or not the game in that room has already begun. I decided to do that by using the customproperties of a room to save an integer which can be either 0 (players are still waiting) or 1 (players are in game). I set the custom properties after getting a callback on the master client that the room was created, however the custom properties don't change after I use SetCustomProperties.

```
    public override void OnCreatedRoom()
{
    base.OnCreatedRoom();
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable roomProps = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
    roomProps["inGame"] = 0;
    PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(roomProps);
}

    public void StartLobbyGame() {
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable roomProps = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
    roomProps["inGame"] = 1;
    PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(roomProps);
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("InGame");
}
```

Any idea why that is?

Comment: where/how do you check if they were changed?

Comment: I had debug logs that i removed so they don't get in your way. Debug.log(roomProps.Count) returns 1
but after using setcustomproperties and then calling Debug.log(CurrentRoom.CustomProperties.Count) i get 0

Comment: You will have to rather check in `OnRoomPropertiesChanged` the changes might not be applied yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by adding the custom property to the room options before creating the room with those options. After that in my start game method i change the value of the property from 0 to 1.

```
 public void CreateRoom(string name)
{
    RoomOptions ropts = new RoomOptions() { IsOpen = true, IsVisible = true, MaxPlayers = 8 };
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable roomProps = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
    roomProps.Add("inGame", 0);
    ropts.CustomRoomProperties = roomProps;
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(name, ropts);
}


    public void StartLobbyGame() {
    PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties["inGame"] = 1;
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("InGame");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty hashtable, so it doesn't contains the key "inGame".
You need to add it first before accessing it using `roomProps["inGame"] = 0`;

You can add keys like that :

```
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable roomProps = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable() { {"inGame", 0} };
```

or

```
roomProps.Add("inGame", 0);
```

Comment: I changed it to use Add instead of what i was doing but i get the same result.

        ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable roomProps = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
        roomProps.Add("inGame", 0);
        PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(roomProps);
        Debug.Log("A: "+ roomProps.Count); //returns 1
        Debug.Log("B: "+ PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties.Count); //returns 0

Comment: This is wrong. For Hashtable, the Photon one and Dictionary in all `roomProps["inGame"] = 0;` means either **add or overwrite** the key `inGame` with value `0`